# Error conversión Console.Writeline

Tags: c#

Necesitaría ayuda para entender la conversión de tipos en C#

Al ejecutar el programa, recibo un error de conversión, debido al tercer parámetro que es el resultado de una multiplicación de dos integers.

No entiendo, el porqué del error, y después de googlear un poco, he visto que en algunos casos algunas personas utilizar algo similar a esto para pasar parámetros, que tampoco logro entender el sentido.Es algo como {1:c} o {1:p1}. No entiendo el sentido de la c o el p1.

```
 class Solution
{
    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        for (int i=1; i<=10; i++)
        {
            int j = n * i;
            Console.WriteLine("{0} x {1} ={3}", n, i, j.ToString());
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La razón es que estas poniendo `{3}`, este indice no es válido, porque no tienes una cuarta variable por parametro para hacer el formato, el índice de formato empieza en 0, como casi todos los elementos indizados del lenguaje, tal como dicen [Trauma](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/34350/4499) y [sioesi](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/34351/4499) en sus respuestas.

Pero haré algo de adición a lo que no entiendes.

Lo que estas haciendo justo ahora con los `"{0}, {1}, {3}"` se llama formato de cadenas, en C# se permite este formato por medio de indices dentro de la cadena encapsulados dentro de `{` y `}` y estos indices corresponden al arreglo de caracteres posterior a la cadena. Estos parámetros obtienen cierta salida al especificarles el formato, por ejemplo:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:P}", 0.012); // Salida: 12.00%
```

Donde la `P` es el especificador de porcentaje, existen otros tipos de especificadores de formato, tales como moneda o incluso puedes controlar el espaciado que tienen los parámetros pasados a la función.

Otros especificadores:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}", 5); // Impresión normal de variable.
Console.WriteLine("{0,-5}'", 6); // Impresión con espaciado hacia la derecha
Console.WriteLine("{0,5}", 7); // Impresion con espaciado hacia la izquierda
Console.WriteLine("{0:C2}", 1500); // Moneda!
Console.WriteLine("{0:d}", DateTime.Now); // Formatos para fecha!
Console.WriteLine("{0:t}", DateTime.Now);
Console.WriteLine("{0:X}", 55231); // Número hex
```

El resultado de este código es el siguiente:

```
5
6    '    
    7
$1,500.00
11/17/2016
12:40 PM
D7BF
```

En los formatos `{:P<num>}`, `num` es la cantidad de digitos que quieres que aparezcan en la salida, aplica practicamente para todos los especificadores.

---

Por último, una pequeña versión mejorada de tu código:

```
static void Main(String[] args)
{
    int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    int j; // Declaramos el que guardará el valor.
    for (int i=1; i<=10; i++)
    {
        j = n * i;
        Console.WriteLine("{0} x {1} = {2}", n, i, j); // No necesitas castear a string.
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

En esta versión, declaré la variable `j` fuera del ciclo `for` dado que estas declarandola cada vez que pasa el ciclo y eso es un pequeño gasto de memoria.

[Fuente, MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

El error que lanza tu codigo es que estas haciendo referencia a un indice que no existe... Pasas 3 argumentos por lo que los valores estan como 0, 1 y 2.

```
int n = 5;
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    int j = n * i;
    Console.WriteLine("{0} x {1} = {2}", n, i, j);
}
```

Comment: Lo que yo decía, pero **mucho** *mas mejor*  **dicho**, si señor :-)

Answer (score 1):

A partir del C# 6.0, puedes utilizar el operador $ para los strings, es mucho menos completo que la opcion de string.format, ya que no puedes aplicarle formatos y tienes que repetir parámetros, pero en la mayoría de los casos es mucho más cómoda y legible:

```
 class Solution
{
    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        for (int i=1; i<=10; i++)
        {
            int j = n * i;
            Console.WriteLine($"{n} x {i} ={j.ToString()}");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sin tener ni idea de C#, ¿ y si en lugar de `{3}` haces `{2}` ?

Si empiezas a contar los argumentos por `0`, no le pasas 3, sino 2.